# How do I get a path alias using the REST API?

Tags: 8, users, path-aliases

I use Drupal 8. I generated path aliases for user entities using the Pathauto module, so /user/1 is accessible through /yourusername.

How can I access the path alias using a GET command (e.g. REST API)?

Comment: In Drupal 8.4, the alias will be included when you fetch the data for a given user, in Drupal 8.3, there is no bulit-in way to get that information. If you use redirect module, it will redirect /user/1 automatically, should also work for REST requests

Comment: Thank you. Can this be displayed using a view? I am running the latest release of Drupal – 8.3.7 @Berdir can you please suggest a redirect module that is compatible with Drupal 8?

Comment: Redirect module has a beta release for Drupal 8 that works fine. And no, I don't think there is views integration to display that either